# Javascript if svg has role add class

Tags: javascript, svg, contains

I'm trying to add a class to an SVG if the  does not have a role="img".

I can add a class to the SVG with role img

```
const imgRole = document.querySelectorAll('svg[role="img"]');

imgRole.forEach(function(el) {
  el.classList.add("my--class");
});
```

However I can't target the SVGs that do not have the role.

I tried to find a way of using not !, but had no success.

if (!el.classList.contains...

I'd appreciate any help in showing me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p:not([role=a])').forEach(p => p.style.color = 'red')
```

```html
<p role="a">lorem ipsum</p>
<p role="not a">lorem ipsum</p>
<p role="a">lorem ipsum</p>
<p role="also not a">lorem ipsum</p>
```

In your case:

```
'svg:not([role="img"])'
```

Comment: I get 'svg:not[role="img"]' is not a valid selector.' error.

Comment: It's working, thanks Konrad. document.querySelectorAll('svg:not([role=img])').forEach(img => img.classList.add('ero'));